# $V_\alpha, X \in V_\alpha$ and $|X|$.

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals, transfinite-induction

I wish to know which $V_\alpha$ contain cardinalities of all its elements (for an ordinal $\alpha$).

I've conjectured that all of them, and tried to prove this by the transfinite induction on $\alpha$.

- $V_0$ contains no elements, so that's true by default.
- Assume that $\forall \beta < \alpha \ \forall A \in V_\beta, |A| \in V_\beta$ for some limit ordinal $\alpha$. Then, if $A \in V_\alpha = \bigcup_{\beta < \alpha} V_\beta$, then there is $\beta < \alpha$ such that $A \in V_\beta$, and by assumption $|A| \in V_\beta$, and as $V_\beta \subseteq V_\alpha$ since $\beta < \alpha$, it follows that $|A| \in V_\alpha$.

However, the successor case is still a mystery to me, so I'm not even sure if it's true.

I would like to know which class of ordinals satisfy it, and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for all ordinals $\alpha \colon V_{\alpha} \cap \mathrm{Ord} = \alpha$. [This follows easily by an induction on $\alpha$.]

Now $\mathcal P(\omega) \in V_{\omega+2}$ but $| \mathcal P(\omega)| \ge \omega_1$ and hence $| \mathcal P(\omega) | \not \in V_{\omega+2}$.

Comment: Interesting. Maybe, limits then?

Comment: If $\kappa$ is a [Beth fixed point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beth_number) then, for all $\alpha < \kappa$, $| V_{\alpha} | = \beth_{\alpha} < \kappa$, thus $|V_{\alpha}| \in V_{\kappa}$ and it follows easily that $V_{\kappa}$ is closed under its $V$-cardinals.

Comment: The same counterexample works for $\omega + \omega$. In fact, being closed under $V$-cardinals is equivalent to being a Beth fixed point. I've covered the one direction in an early comment. The other one follows by basically the same argument - we need $| V_{\alpha} | = \beth_{\alpha} \in V_{\kappa} \cap \mathrm{Ord} = \kappa$. Thus $\kappa$ is closed under the Beth function and thus $\kappa = \sup_{\alpha < \kappa} \beth_{\alpha} = \beth_{\kappa}$.

Comment: Thanks, let me see if I can prove these things myself.

Comment: You may be interested to learn that there is - provably in $\mathrm{ZFC}$ - a club class of Beth fixed points. This follows from the [normal function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_lemma_for_normal_functions), observing that $\alpha \mapsto \beth_\alpha$ is a normal function.

Comment: Dear Stefan, I guess that it's not true that $\forall \alpha < \kappa, |V_\alpha| = \beth_\alpha$. Of course, the counterexample is trivial: $\alpha = 0$, so I assume you've wanted to write something else.

Comment: Oh, I guess, $|V_\alpha| \leq \beth_\alpha$ should do.

Comment: Right, I was off by $\omega$. $| V_{\omega + \alpha}| = \beth_{\alpha}$.